# Plot visibility by checkmark in GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have from 2-30 plots where I want to control the visibility by checkmark selection in a GUI (Guide). But I can't get it to work. Please help.

Here my code with two simple plots:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
X1=[1 2 3 4]
Y1=[-1 -2 -3 -4]
X2=[1 2 3 4]
Y2=[1 2 3 4]
handles.handle_plot1 = plot(X1,Y1);
handles.handle_plot2 = plot(X2,Y2);
guidata(hObject, handles);


% --- Executes on button press in checkbox1.
function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   handles.handle_plot1 = handles.handle_plot1
   if (get(hObject,'Value')) == 1 
       set(handle_plot1, 'visible' , 'on')
   else 
       set(handle_plot1, 'visible' , 'off')
   end


% --- Executes on button press in checkbox2.
function checkbox2_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
   handles.handle_plot2 = handles.handle_plot2
   if (get(hObject,'Value')) == 1  
       set(handle_plot2, 'visible' , 'on')
   else 
       set(handle_plot2, 'visible' , 'off')
   end
```

But I get this error:

```
Undefined function or variable 'handle_plot1'.

Error in test>checkbox1_Callback (line 91)
       set(handle_plot1, 'visible' , 'on')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Literally as the error states, you haven't defined the variable `handle_plot1`. You probably meant the first line of your `checkbox1_callback`  function to be `handle_plot1 = handles.handle_plot1`, not what you wrote (which does nothing) `handles.handle_plot1 = handles.handle_plot1`

Comment: True, thanks but then I get another error: Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Line/set
Invalid or deleted object.

Error in test>checkbox1_Callback (line 91)
       set(handle_plot1, 'visible' , 'on')

Comment: You could try to assign the plots to a variable `p1 = plot(X1,Y1);` and then save it to workspace `assignin('base','p1',p1);`. In your `checkbox1_callback` you can load the handle from the workspace by `p1 = evalin('base','p1');`. However you should check whether this handle exisits to aviod errors.

Comment: @Irreducible It's not really good advice to use `evalin` to avoid manually getting variables, if you created `p1` it would be better to pass this as an input to the function. @J.Birch without your GUI, it's hard to diagnose that error. It suggests that the referenced handle object doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Hi Wolfie. You are right. I did manage to create a functional code with: set(gca, 'NextPlot', 'add'); and handle_plot1 = handles.handle_plot1. I do however have issues with plotting in the same axes. Here is my code if you are interested, any help is very appreciated: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/358534-visibility-of-several-plot-in-the-same-axes-by-checkmark-in-gui

Comment: @Wolfie thanks for the advice.